# Focus on one of the two and the answer will come to you

Tags: knowledge, enigmatic-puzzle

**Five directors are listed in the puzzle below. There is an additional director who didn't make the list, the one labeled as "(Extra)". Who is that director?**

---

*You can't fly but you can always try.
 Just make sure it's off the shore.
 If you can't, you'll land on water - no harm..., always works like a charm.*

David Fincher ----- ----
Ebrahim Irajzad ------- ------
Tim Klok ---- -----
Lee Philips --- -----
 Fanny Ardant ------- -----

(no need to "apply" *the text*)

(Extra):

?       ----- -----

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think the missing director is

> M. Night Shyamalan

Reasoning

> Given the spaces, the movies for each director are
>  David Fincher - **FIGHT CLUB**
>  Ebrahim Irajzad - **SEARING SUMMER**
>  Tim Klok - **COPY PASTE**
>  Lee Philips - **THE SPELL**
>  Fanny Ardant - **STALIN'S COUCH**
>  Each of these movies contains a word which is one letter different from one of the classical five senses, in order - **SIGHT**, **HEARING**, **TASTE**, **SMELL**, **TOUCH**.
>  So the last movie must be [THE **SIXTH SENSE**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Sixth_Sense)

Comment: That's exactly right and very fast. Well done!